# SuiteScript Create Record has an ID

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am curious about something in SuiteScript and I am not finding an answer easily.

When a record is created in SuiteScript: nlapiCreateRecord('recordType', {recordmode:'dynamic'});, I am curious to know if the record's ID is also created. Or does that process only happen on the nlapiSubmitRecord(); command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nlapiCreateRecord()` only initializes the record and returns an `nlobjRecord` object  for your script to work on.  Nothing is committed to the database until you submit the record using `nlapiRecordSubmit()`.  The application cannot decide what the internal id will be until submitted, as other records could be added between when the record is created and when it's submitted.

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies things for me.